# How to use bitwise NOT operator with shift operator in C#?

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit, bit-shift

I don't understand how this expression works.

```
~(1 << 1) = -3
```

What I do understand is that 1 << 1 has a value of 10 in binary and 2 in base 10. How did it get a -3 with the NOT operator? How does shift operators work with NOT operators?

Comment: In general `~x == -x - 1` (following from the definition of negation, `-x = ~x + 1`)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The bitwise inverse operator is entirely separate from the shift here.

You've started with input of 10 (binary) - which has a full 32-bit representation of

```
00000000_00000000_00000000_00000010
```

The bitwise inverse is therefore:

```
11111111_11111111_11111111_11111101
```

... which is the binary representation of -3 (in 32-bit [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)).